# I am giving a link in href for going to web route but it is not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<div class="card-header  text-center {{{$alarm->status}}}" style="
color: green;"><a href="http://www.voalerts.com/public/detail/{{{$plantdetail->PlantID}}}/{{{$alarm->equipmentid}}}" style="
color: #f8f9fa;;" >{{$alarm->equipmentDescription}}</a></div>
```

- List item

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjcjS.png)

- List item

Comment: It is showing this type of error in error_log PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/ixed.7.1.lin' - /opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/ixed.7.1.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: This isn't an issue with the link or Laravel looks like something is wrong with your php configuration. Check that no-debug-non-zts-20151012/ixed.7.1.lin exists in the extensions folder if not you'll have to install it.

Comment: yes but when we click on the link that i have set this error message is showing :- "Redirect URI, /404.html, does not use one of the allowed redirect protocols: http, https

Comment: can you tell me why this is comming..

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't see that image you've got there. Try changing the link in your anchor tag to just "/public/detail/{{{$plantdetail->PlantID}}}/{{{$alarm->equipmentid}}}" and it should work, you don't need the domain name there.

Comment: Have you created a "route" for that path in Laravel & assign an alias to it ?
Link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes